# FB login authentication mechanics

Tags: java, authentication, facebook-login

I read online and understand how to use the FB connect and how to create an app that uses the fb login. What I want to know is whether it is possible to manipulate the data between the authentication.

So here's what I am confuse about. So we have

1. FB server
2. my application
3. my server.

So when I open my application, my application will ask for fb login and pw, we send those info to FB server. The FB server then give my application a token, then my application will send the token to my server, then my server will verify with FB server? Is this how it works?

If that's the way it works why there's no hacking in FB login, can't people make fake tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses OAuth 2.0, which is a current standard for open authorization. This is a short description from wikipedia:

> OAuth provides client applications a 'secure delegated access' to
> server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process
> for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server
> resources without sharing their credentials. Designed specifically to
> work with Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), OAuth essentially allows
> access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization
> server, with the approval of the resource owner, or end-user. The
> client then uses the access token to access the protected resources
> hosted by the resource server.[1] OAuth is commonly used as a way for
> web surfers to log into third party web sites using their Google,
> Facebook or Twitter passwords, without worrying about their access
> credentials being compromised.

You can read the RFC specification for more details: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
You can also read information about the different integrations: http://oauth.net/2/

You cannot create a fake token. The user receives a token after typing his username and passwords, which means stealing his token is equivalent to stealing his credentials, as the token is randomly generated.

I will explain the flow shortly:
I'm an user, using in general facebook and your application. I log in facebook and reach your application in facebook or via external link and click on it. Then facebook will ask me if I want to share my personal information with your application (this is because I am logged in. If I were not, then it would ask me for my username and password). If I agree, facebook will send an access token to your application and with it you will access of my personal information. Thus this access will be highly restricted and you won't be able to do anything harmful and as well it will expire after a couple of time, depending on the implementation, but should be around one hour.

Answer (score 0):

By your question , even a set of "fake" credentials for all purposes of you app will be a vaid login ( because the user exists on facebook) . Facebook is essentially authenticating that the person is a valid person. A person cannot make a fake facebook token because it is signed