# An active access token must be used to query information in facebook feed api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to share facebook story to user timeline from facebook app. On home page we are accessing user permission to post and retrieve information (email,read_stream,publish_actions,
publish_stream,user_likes).

In another page user doing some activities in our app. So we want share it as facebook story:

My script

```
FB.api(
    "/me/feed",
    "POST",
    {
        "object": {
            "message": "This is a test message"
        }
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response);
      }else{
          console.log(response.error)
      }
    }
);
```

I'm getting `Object {message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.", type: "OAuthException", code: 2500}`

Is this because of asking permission in some other page, token is invalid?

Also whether we can share facebook story using this api?

Need suggestions.

**Edited** :

```
    FB.init({
    appId : appId,
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth : true
// enable OAuth 2.0
});



function login() {  
     FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                isPageLiked(response);
            } else {
                //alert("no permission");
            }
        }, {scope: 'email,read_stream,publish_actions,publish_stream,user_likes'});
}


function isPageLiked(response){

        var page_id = "397640857040166"; //coca cola
        FB.api('/me/likes/'+page_id, function(response) {
// like response

        });
```

In this to call `isPageLiked` I'm not sending access token, fb script will handle it. Then for same session in another page (next page) if I call feed api why it is not taking access token?

Comment: You should get familiar with the mechanism of the security protocol used by facebook, OAuth 2.0. You need an access token, generated by facebook to be able to access the personal information, regardless if this user is you. You can check my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770579/fb-login-authentication-mechanics/23771814#23771814

Comment: So if access token time expires(if we wont set time for expire) we need to ask post permission again from user?.

Comment: Basically yes. You will also receive a refresh token, which could be used to retrieve again an access token.

Comment: Is it good practice to store plain access token in DB ?

Comment: You can check http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41769/best-practices-on-securely-storing-access-tokens
For further questions you can search in google and in the official RFC, which I linked in the question in my first comment.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0#token shows that we no need to store access token,browser will handle this. I have one question I'll update question